# Accessing Photo File

Tags: android, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I use the standard TTakePhotoFromCameraAction in my application in order to take a photo.

What I would like to do, is when the user closes the application and then open it again, the last taken photo to be uploaded.

I know how to use [SharedPreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799540/accessing-androids-sharedpreferences-class-from-delphi) in delphi, but I don't know what is the filename & path of the photo it self!

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

The `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction.OnDidFinishTaking` event gives you a `Bitmap` of the taken photo. It is then your responsibility to save it where and how you need it. `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` does not save it for you.

Comment: Then how comes it is saved in gallery?
I am afraid that if I save it, I will have 2 files in the storage media.

Comment: I do not see anything in Firemonkey's source code that saves a captured camera photo to the gallery. However, I do see that `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` calls `JFMXMediaLibrary.takeImageFromCamera()` and Embarcadero's implementation of the `JFMXMediaLibrary` interface is hidden inside of the `com.embarcadero.firemonkey.medialibrary.FMXMediaLibrary` java class, which I don't see any source code for. So it is *possible* that Embarcadero is secretly saving captured photos to the gallery without FireMonkey knowing about it, but I can't imagine why they would want or need to do that.

Comment: Especially since `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` is providing the photo data to the app to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Maybe it is not Embarcadero JFMXMediaLibrary the one saving it... maybe Android OS.. or the Manufacturer Camera applet. But again, why other applications pictures are not saved in the Gallery but in a particular folder?

Comment: Can't answer that since we can't see how Embarcadero is invoking the camera, whether directly or via an Intent or what. Android exposes different ways to access the camera, so maybe different APIs have different behaviors, or maybe Embarcadero is omitting a flag that tells the camera to ignore the Gallery, or ...

Comment: Alright,
I give up.. I can manage the double saving.
but I tried the following code to save the bitmap to a file:
Img.Bitmap.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine((System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath, 'abitmap.bmp'));
But it does not save the file!!!
What a I missing??????

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample showing you how to do it coming with delphi samples:

C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\FireMonkeyMobile\PhotoEditorDemo