# firemonkey xe5 save captured image with specified name

Tags: android, android-camera, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

In `firemonkey xe5` there was sample how to capture image and show it as a `bitmap`, is it possible to change the image name, right after capturing, with a source code?

I've tried to use this code :

```
Image.SaveToFile(GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'myimage.jpg')
```

on this procedure :

```
procedure TForm2.TakePhotoFromCameraAction1DidFinishTaking(Image: TBitmap);
begin

end;
```

but nothing happened.

Comment: I cannot comment on why "nothing happened", but I do know that on Android, capturing a camera image puts the image into Android's Picture Gallery (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099963/). There is no way to know the filename for that file (unless you monitor the filesystem for changes). What your code is doing is saving a separate copy of the image data to a different file. You are not renaming the original file, which is still in the Gallery.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention before , it's said 'nothing happened' but it is actually save my captured image into Android's picture gallery with it's original name , is it still possible to change/rename ?

and if it's possible what kind of code should i use ?
thanks before

Comment: You are not saving into the Gallery, `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` is saving into the Gallery before giving you the `TBitmap`. As I said, it does NOT give you access to the filename that it saved. So you have two choices: 1) watch the filesystem yourself to discover what file was created, or 2) do not use `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` at all, use JNI to [access the camera directly](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) instead. Amongst other things, that allows you to specify your own destination filename, if you want the image saved to a file at all.