# How to create and show the options menu in android for a delphi apk?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe6

I have used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18800697/1959171) to save ini-like information as cross platform method.

For Android I want to show that tree dot menu that I believe is called context menu.

I suppose there is a API call to read and show the editor.

What is the Delphi like style for doing that?

EDIT: I corrected from "context" to "options" menu according the comment below.

Comment: iirc its name is ["options menu"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), in Android 3.0 or higher it appears in the action bar

Comment: @mjn thanks for the info, I was not certain about how was that called. Now I have a strong information.